# Can I refactor name libcocos2dcpp.so?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-2.x

libcocos2dcpp.so is located at path proj.android\libs\armeabi

**1)** I want to learn to modify how it looks after changing the name "**libcocos2dcpp.so**" to some "randomname.so"

(Intention being, not sure but it might help in protecting my game's source code if people won't know in which thing it is made, I mean **cpp** because libcocos2dcpp.so has **cpp** in its end)

**2)** Also, is this libcocos2dcpp.so created newly every time I build my code or does it remains same through its entire life time?

Comment: Wrong assumption, save yourself the hassle. Decompiling a binary back into C++ is unfeasible and won't yield usable results; someone who knows where to start doing this won't be put off by the name of the included library.

Comment: So, are you saying that this binary which is compiled, remains same through it life and isn't build each time I build my cocos2d-x project?

Comment: No, that's not what I said; where are you getting that? Please read the comment again to comprehend what I said.

Comment: which version of cocos2d-x did you use?

Comment: @323go , why would it yield unusable results?

Comment: Do you know *anything* about how compilers work? Or computers, for that matter?

Comment: @323go Yes, I do know a bit but I am not sure why would it lead to unusable results? As you can see that einverne has already answered it below. And my assumption was that a person if sees librandomNamecpp.so then he wouldn't be sure that I've made it in cocos2d which would make it difficult for him to target in finding source files!

Comment: @323go And the reason why I asked libcocos2dcpp.so remains as it is throughout because I am not sure what goes inside it, I mean is it just the framework files compiled since the beginning or does it also includes my source files to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your lib name by using `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME` in the Android.mk file . According to ANDROID-MK document under Android-NDK folder:

```
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME
    This variable is optional, and allows you to redefine the name of
    generated files. By default, module <foo> will always generate a
    static library named lib<foo>.a or a shared library named lib<foo>.so,
    which are standard Unix conventions.

    You can override this by defining LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME, For example:

        LOCAL_MODULE := foo-version-1
        LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libfoo

    NOTE: You should not put a path or file extension in your
    LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME, these will be handled automatically by the
    build system.
```

You can just rename your lib file name as

```
LOCAL_MODULE := randomname
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := librandomname
```

so the build system will automatically build the lib as `librandomname.so`.

And don't forget to change the code in Android `Activity`:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("randomname");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me where to put the code System.loadLibrary("randomname"); because in the Cocos2dxActivity.java I found the following code>>                       protected void onLoadNativeLibraries() {
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
            String libName = bundle.getString("android.app.lib_name");
            System.loadLibrary(libName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: I think the code block above became a bit mess. So here it is again. In Cocos2dxActivity.java I found,                                               String libName = bundle.getString("android.app.lib_name");      System.loadLibrary(libName);                                                                 So what should I replace here?